# How to Disable some items of TextBox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, textbox

**Hi**

I want to disable some items of the textbox like "Right to left reading order". 
I don't like these, but I do not found an explication why these are there and if is correct disable/remove them.

You can see here a little image with the items that I want avoid.

http://www.imageupload.org/?d=96631C971

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it's not possible to disable items from the default context menu, you can create a new one and customize the items for the textbox like this.

```
var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy", (s, ea) => textBox1.Copy()));
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Paste", (s, ea) => textBox1.Paste()));
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Undo", (s, ea) => textBox1.Undo()));
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Select All", (s, ea) => textBox1.SelectAll()));
textBox1.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
```

Note: use `contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("-"))` for separators.

Comment: This looks a very fast solution :) . But you know if is good idea, avoid the other items?

Comment: @Marco by default `textBox1.ContextMenu` is null and my guess is the operating system provides the default context menu from your image and I don't believe there is a way to disable selective items from it. If you want to disable all of it, just set `textBox1.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();`

Comment: @Marco, if you don't expect your target audience to need things like right-to-left reading order or strange and crazy IMEs, then there's nothing wrong with customizing the menu. Just make sure you implement all the basic stuff!

Comment: Bala, Mike thanks for your replies.
The solution is good for me.